# Symbols in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What is the rationale for Symbols in Clojure to be bound to an underlying object and have an optional separate value ? Perhaps something elementary I am missing but would be great if someone could point out the Why.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### General intro:

Symbols in any Lisp are used as identifiers. If you're going to refer to the value of a variable, say, you need to have a way of naming it; that's what symbols are for. Remember that all Lisp code gets translated at read time to Lisp data structures; identifiers must also be represented by some data structure and it happens to be the symbol. Upon encountering a symbol, `eval` dispatches to some kind of a "name lookup" operation.

Moving from Lisp generalities to Clojure particulars, the behaviour of the Clojure eval / compiler is that upon encountering a symbol, it takes it to be a name for either a `let`-introduced local variable or function parameter *or* the name of an entry in a namespace. Actually only non-namespace-qualified symbols may be used in the first capacity (meaning symbols of the form `foo` and not `some-namespace/foo`).

### A roughly sketched example:

For a non-namespace-qualified symbol `foo`, if a `let` binding / function parameter of name `foo` is found, the symbol evaluates to its value. If not, the symbol gets transformed to the form `*ns*/foo` (`*ns*` denotes the current namespace) and an attempt is made to look up a curresponding entry in `*ns*`; if there is such an entry, its value is returned, if not, an exception is thrown.

Note that a symbol like `identity`, when used in namespace `quux`, will be resolved to `clojure.core/identity` through an intermediate step in which an entry under `quux/identity` is discovered; this will normally *refer* to `clojure.core/identity`. That's an implementation detail one doesn't think of when coding intuitively, but which I find impossible not to mention when trying to explain this.

A symbol which is already namespace-qualified (something like a `zip/root` in a namespace which `refer`s to `clojure.zip` without `use`'ing it) will be looked up in the appropriate namespace.

There's some added complexity with macros (which can only occur in operator position), but it's not really something relevant to the behaviour of symbols themselves.

### Vars vs Symbols:

Note that **in Clojure, symbols are not themselves storage locations** -- Vars are. So when I say in the above that a symbol gets looked up in a namespace, what I mean is that `eval` looks up the Var named by the symbol resolved to its namespace-qualified form and then takes the value of that. The special form `var` (often abbreviated to `#'`) modifies this behaviour so that the Var object itself is returned. The mechanics of symbol-to-Var resolution are unchanged, though.

### Closing remarks:

Note that all this means that symbols are only "bound" to objects in the sense that `eval`, when evaluating a symbol, goes on to look for some further object. The symbol itself has no "slot" or "field" for an object to be bound to it; any impression that a symbol is "bound" to some object is due to `eval`'s workings. This is a Clojure characteristic, as in some Lisps symbols do themselves act as storage locations.

Finally, one can use the usual quoting mechanism to prevent the evaluation of a symbol: in `'foo`, the symbol `foo` will not be evaluted (so no name lookup of any sort will be performed); it'll be returned unchanged instead.

*In response to OP's comment:* Try this for fun:

```
(defmacro symbol?? [x]
  (if (symbol? x)
    true
    false))

(def s 1)
(symbol? s)
; => false
(symbol?? s)
; => true
(symbol? 's)
; => true
(symbol?? 's)
; => false
```

The last one explained: `'s` is shorthand for `(quote s)`; this is a list structure, not a symbol. A macro operates on its arguments passed in directly, without being evaluated; so in `(symbol?? 's)` it actually sees the `(quote s)` list structure, which is of course not itself a symbol -- although when passed to `eval`, it would evaluate to one.

Comment: Thanks Michal !

 Here is a scenario that had me confused. Lets say there is (def s 1). Now (symbol? 's) evaluates to true while for (symbol? s) result is false. Is the quote used to access the underlying object for symbols ?

Comment: You last sentence explains it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Icarus: Yes, precisely! When you say `(symbol? s)`, `s` gets evaluated (in this case to `1`) before the `symbol?` function sees it, so you're basically asking if `1` is a symbol (which it isn't). If you quote the symbol, it gets passed to `symbol?` unchanged. (`eval` operates on data structures, so the symbol in-memory representation will in both cases have already been constructed by the reader; the quoting makes `eval` leave it unevaluated). Clojure's function-calling semantics are call-by-value; you'd have to use a macro to change that. In fact, I might edit one in in a second. :-)

Answer (score 28):

There may be some confusion here from the different usages of the term "symbol" in Common Lisp and in Clojure.

In Common Lisp, a "symbol" is a location in memory, a place where data can be stored.  The "value" of a symbol is the data stored at that location in memory.

In Clojure, a "symbol" is just a name.  It has no value.

When the Clojure compiler encounters a symbol, it tries to resolve it as

1. a Java class name (if the symbol contains a dot)
2. a local (as with "let" or function parameters)
3. a Var in the current Namespace
4. a Var referred from another Namespace

The Var, as a previous poster pointed out, represents a storage location.

There are good reasons why Clojure separates Vars from Symbols.  First, it avoids the annoyance of Common Lisp's automatically-interned symbols, which can "pollute" a package with unwanted symbols.

Secondly, Clojure Vars have special semantics with regard to concurrency.  A Var has a exactly one "root binding" visible to all threads.  (When you type "def" you are setting the root binding of a Var.)  Changes to a Var made within a thread (using "set!" or "binding") are visible only to that thread and its children.